# Custom Assemblers in Fatwire

Tags: fatwire

URL Generating by `<GetBlobUrl></GetBlobUrl>` tag in Fatwire is very lengthy and it includes System parameters. More over this URL's are not Search-engine friendly. Does custom Assemblers help us to convert into shorter form ? If so can you give me some tips to write Custom Assembler.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote you must use the URL Assemblers provided in FatWire.

How to do it? well it depends on what you want.

In Generel you muss write a java class that implements the com.fatwire.cs.core.uri.Assembler interface. You will need the FatWire JavaDocs for this.

When you are finished, compile your class into a .jar file and deploy it on Content Server. If you are using Satellite Server you must deploy it there as well.

After Deploying it you must register you new assembler in the ServletRequest.properties file.

After deployment and registration you must restart Content Server and if you have them, your Satellite servers as well.

It's not a beginners task.

You can read more here: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ips-link/message/17515

Fatwire is shipped with two Assemblers:

Query Assembler (default) and 
QueryAsPathInfo Assembler

The QueryAsPathInfo Assembler could be what you are looking for (ootb).

FatWire even provides the sourcecode for that assembler.

Should be on your FatWire CD under: /ContentServer/FirstSiteII/PrettyURL/src/com/fatwire/firstsite/uri/FSIIAssembler.java

Or look in the forum above.